# Регулярное выражение для шестизначного числа, в десятичной системе счисления

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Проверить является ли заданная строка шестизначным числом, записанным в десятичной системе счисления без нулей в старших разрядах. Примеры правильных выражений: 123456, 234567. Примеры неправильных выражений: 1234567, 12345.

Есть какие наброски, но не могу довести до ума

```
import re
a=input("Введите строку: ")
for i in range(100000,999999):
    b= re.fullmatch(r'i' ,a) is not None
    if b == True:
        print("Является")
```

Требуется ваша помощь

Comment: Старший разряд это ведь первая цифра числа?

Comment: Да,старшие разряды это первые цифры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регуляркой проверяем что первый символ входит в диапазон от 1 до 9, а после идут 5 цифр (от 0 до 9):

```
import re

def is_ok(num: str) -> bool:
    return bool(re.search('^[1-9]\d{5}$', num))

for num in ['123456', '234567', '034567', '1234567', 'A12345', '12345']:
    print(num, is_ok(num))
```

Результат:

```
123456 True
234567 True
034567 False
1234567 False
A12345 False
12345 False
```

---

**PS.**

С учетом кода в вопросе:

```
num = input("Введите строку: ")
if is_ok(num):
    print("Является")
```

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать по какой причине поставили минус моему ответу

Comment: А как на счёт `A12345`? Это десятичное число?

Comment: @PetSerAl, блин, в точку!